# Ionic 3 app.component.ts showing red line error and not working

Tags: angular, ionic3

We have an assignment from school and the teacher had some code that we had to copy into the app.component.ts but its not working for me and showing as error and wont compile anything. How do I fix this? I attached the screenshot

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qJ0v.png)

Thank you

Comment: I think that code should be in app.component*.html* instead of *.ts*

Comment: the app component is there by default and I was asked to copy the code into that file specifically

Comment: Okay nevermind I figured it out. Thanks. The teacher had written the wrong file name in the pdf.

Comment: In this case, please close this question as it is not clear enough for others how to help here.